# Implicit function theorem in economics

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I just cant understand how author substite the second two equations into the first equation and get the system. Pls someone show it step by step.

$$Y=C+I+G$$
$$C=a+b(Y-T)$$
$$I=i_0-i_1r$$
$$M^s=c_1Y-c_2r$$

Author says:

> We follow the standard method of substituting the second two equations into the first equation and simplifying to obtain the system.

and he get this
$$(1-b)Y+i_1r=a+i_0+G-bT $$
$$c_1Y-c_2r=M^s$$

Comment: What about taking a sheet of paper and a pencil and doing exactly what the author said? Then simple rearranging gives the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just directly substitute the second and third equation into the first, and move things around:
\begin{align}
Y &= C + I + G \tag{given} \\
&= \left[ a + b(Y-T)\right] + \left[ i_0 - i_1r\right] + G \tag{substitution} \\
&= bY - i_1r + a + i_0 + G - bT \tag{basic rearranging}
\end{align}
Now, move the first two terms of the RHS to the LHS to get 
\begin{align}
Y- bY + i_1r &= a + i_0 + G - bT \\
\end{align}
Hence:
\begin{align}
(1- b)Y + i_1r &= a + i_0 + G - bT
\end{align}

The equation $c_1Y-c_2r=M^s$ is exactly the fourth equation you're given